# How can I set Openstack with NAT remapping?

Tags: networking, virtualization, linux-kvm, openstack

I am using hypervisor as KVM and have one server to host Openstack services. I want to access my cloud server and instances(via floating IPs).

Because of the network limitations I am not able to create bridge network. So I had to go with NAT, but with NAT, since the IP is different than host, I can not have external access to server and dashboard. So far, I could not find a solution to work around. I wonder if it is possible to modify the IP mapped by NAT, or using mapped address instead of host address as installing Openstack?

Comment: "*I can not have external access to server and dashboard*"... can you try to setup the NAT config with internal IP addresses then? I'm not familiar with OpenStack so just a question.

Comment: I have tried to give NAT the internal IP, then lost the internet connectivity. I just think ethernet interface and NAT cant work on same IP, or not possible with convenient methods. So, looking for way around. 
https://www.quora.com/Can-your-internal-IP-be-the-same-as-the-external-one/answer/Phillip-Remaker?share=bb399196&srid=QATt

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/linuxonibm/liaag/wkvm/wkvm_c_net_nat.htm#fntarg_1

Comment: Maybe you also need to add a static route on the interface as well then to ensure it also has to the route for the other non-NAT'd traffic for the Internet. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-route-add/ again just some ideas and nothing definitive since I cannot test myself so FYI at a minimum at least.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the nested virtualisation(since OpenStack uses its own hypervisor). I could overcome this issue as enabling hypervisor(KVM in my case) for nested virtualisation. And after creating bridge interfaces over ethernet interface, I was able to use NAT'ed network into KVM as public network for the VMs in OpenStack.